# Thor is not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor

I have installed Ruby 1.9.2 along with installing the rails gem.  I have now tried to create a new rails application with:

```
$ rails new foo -T
```

I am immediately prompted with

```
Thor is not available.
If you ran this command from a git checkout of Rails, please make sure thor is installed
```

I have thor installed and I have no clue what to do. Please help.

*Warning, I'm a rookie at this.*

Comment: Are you on Windows? Mac? Linux? How do you know you have Thor installed?

Comment: Sorry, I am on a Mac. I gem installed thor and I am capable of viewing the --help and -v of Thor. I assume that means it's installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

I had Ruby 1.9.2 installed on my Mac OS 10.7 and Xcode 4.2 installed. Thor does not work well with the newest Xcode and once I installed Ruby 1.9.3 everything seemed to work fine.

Comment: I had that same problem on ruby 2.3.1.  Re-installing ruby worked for me.